# upload audio in php using jquery ajax

Tags: php, file-upload

I am uploading `.mp3` audio in `php` I am getting `$_FILES['audio_name']['name']` but not getting

```
$_FILES['audio_name']['tmp_name']
$_FILES['audio_name']['size']
$_FILES['audio_name']['type']
```

why this is occurring.

Comment: Because error happens? Error type is in `['audio_name']['error']`

Comment: yes I debug error code is 1 I update php.in for upload _max_file size,post_max_size but not working

Comment: Restart web server, make sure new values are used, check error code again.

Comment: I also restated xmapp but not working

Comment: issue has been resolved